# Meteor JS: Cron job that parses XML

Tags: jquery, xml, cron, meteor

I have a cron job setup in Meteor (https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-cron).

Here is my code:

```
var onetKeys = ["17-0000.00",
          "27-0000.00",
          "37-0000.00",
          "13-0000.00",
          "21-0000.00",
          "15-0000.00",
          "47-0000.00",
          "25-0000.00",
          "45-0000.00",
          "35-0000.00",
          "29-0000.00",
          "49-0000.00",
          "23-0000.00",
          "19-0000.00",
          "11-0000.00",
          "43-0000.00",
          "39-0000.00",
          "51-0000.00",
          "33-0000.00",
          "41-0000.00",
          "53-0000.00"];

console.log("[+] ==== Cron Jobs ====");

Meteor.startup(function(){

  cron = new Cron();

  cron.addJob(500, function(){

    var params = [], finalUrl;

    $.each(onetKeys, function(i, onet){
      params.push("onet=" + onet);
      params.push("cn=100");
      params.push("rs=1&re=500");
      finalUrl = params.join("&");

      Meteor.call('retrieveJobs', finalUrl, function(error, results){
        console.log('GOT JOBS');
        $('job', results.content).each(function(){
          var jvid = $(this).find('jvid').text();
          if(!Jobs.findOne({jvid: jvid})) {
            options = {}
            options.title = $(this).find('title').text();
            options.company = $(this).find('company').text();
            options.address = $(this).find('location').text();
            options.url = $(this).find('url').text();
            options.jvid = jvid;
            options.dateacquired = $(this).find('dateacquired').text();
            var id = createJob(options);
            console.log("Job Created: " + id);
          }
        });
      });
    });
  })
})
```

The code above is in `project_root/cron.js` which will execute with the client. I am needing to move this out to the server, but am not sure how to process XML without the help of jQuery (sad, I know). Any good examples of how to parse XML in JavaScript without jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search here: https://www.npmjs.org/search?q=xml.

There are
[several](https://www.npmjs.org/package/xml2js) 
[Node.js](https://www.npmjs.org/package/xml-parser)
[XML](https://www.npmjs.org/package/xml-simple)
[parsers](https://www.npmjs.org/package/node-xml)
out there. Pick the one that suits you and use it.